# Difficulties to decide on model formulation and to identify dependent and independent variables

Tags: regression, modeling, interaction, ordinal-data, independence

Imagine a disease whose exact mechanisms are unknown and can lead to different phenotypes. Although there likely is a continuum between the different phenotypes, these are categorized (as ordinal variable `Diagnosis`) based on specific parameters (`Selected symptoms`).

[image: Variable relationships]

I am interested in the relationship between `Other clinical variables` (interval scaled, affected by the disease as well) and `Diagnosis`, which I consider to be a proxy of disease phenotype by the intermediary of `Selected symptoms` (I think this is equivalent to saying that `Disease phenotype` is a latent variable?). However, I also know that some environmental variables (`Environment`), specifically `Temperature`, will affect the expression of the phenotype in the form of `Other clinical variables` (e.g., heart rate will be higher in a hotter environment, despite still being the same phenotype).

So my first question is, how can I decide what to use as the dependent and independent variable in regression when both are observations or based on observations? On one hand I think I could investigate the predictive capabilities of `Other clinical variables` for `Diagnosis` (`Diagnosis ~ Heart.Rate`, with an ordinal regression) but I think it would also be justifiable to investigate whether individuals with a certain `Diagnosis` have higher heart rates (`Heart.Rate ~ Diagnosis`, with a linear regression or ordinal ANOVA).

The second question is how can I add the environment/temperature to the equation (or should I consider it at all). I believe that since temperature directly affects `other clinical variables`, it would be wrong to use both as predictors (potentially wrong model: `Diagnosis ~ Heart.Rate + Temperature`, with an ordinal regression), which would leave me with using a linear model where `Diagnosis` and `Temperature` predict `Heart.Rate`.

Graphically I see a relationship between some variables and `Diagnosis` but it is not significant with ANOVA while it is with ordinal regression (with more or less inverse models). I am aware that I should not focus too much on p-values (which BTW are adjusted for multiple comparisons since I have multiple `Other clinical variables` considered separately in analogous models). Of course the choice of model will be based on the statistical rationale and not on the p-values, but obviously ordinal regression is better suited to take into account the ordinal nature of `Diagnosis` than ANOVA or a linear model (I have also tried ordinal ANOVA but it cannot consider numeric covariates).

**TL;DR: How can I analyze the relationship between `Diagnosis` and `Other clinical variables` while taking `Environment` into account?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a latent variable is one that cannot be directly observed. I'm not sure about whether phenotype is latent in your case, but usually a phenotype is based on observed characteristics. However, there are surely some diseases where the characteristics are hard to observe -- I know there are some that require an autopsy!

Second, which variables are dependent and independent is not really a *statistical* question. You have identified the problem. The question is really which thing you are interested in. If you are interested in going from observed symptoms to a diagnosis, then diagnosis is the dependent variable. If you are interested in the mechanism of how the disease causes the symptoms, then the symptom is the DV.

Also, the direction of causation between a disease and its symptoms and other clinical variables can go disease causes symptoms, or symptoms cause disease, or neither, or both.

But the regression model itself doesn't care about causality.